# Asynchronous call to webservice in MVC 4 web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, webservice-client

I am building my first real MVC4 application and I have run into following issue.

I have a model for "User" class. Data for it are obtained through asynchronous call to webservice:

```
public sealed class AdminDMSEntities
{
    public List<User> UserList { get; private set; }

    public AdminDMSEntities()
    {
        this.UserList = new List<User>(0);
        ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
        client.GetUsersCompleted += (s, e) => 
        {
            if (e.Result == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("No users were retrieved");

            UserList = new List<User>(0);
            e.Result.ForEach(w => this.UserList.Add(new User(w.Guid, w.TrusteeType, w.Username, w.Email, w.LastLogin, w.PasswordChanged, w.IsUsingTempPassword)));               
        };

        client.GetUsersAsync();
    }        
}
```

I intend to use this class as I would use class derived from DbContext (if I could use Entity Framework which I cant). So far I have only users in the class.

I am using tis class in UsersController like this:

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private AdminDMSEntities adminEntities = new AdminDMSEntities();
    //
    // GET: /User/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(adminEntities.UserList);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I will end up with InvalidOperationException, because controller is not waiting for async call completion and passes UserList to the view before it is properly filled with users.

I can have the call synchronous for the time being, but it is very likely I will be forced to use asynchronous calls later, so I would like to know how to ensure, that controller will wait for async call to be completed before UserList is passed to view...

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I have tried the approach with AsyncController as listed below, currently I have added this to AdminDMS entities class:

```
public static async Task<AdminDMSEntities> AdminDMSEntitiesAsync()
    {
        AdminDMSEntities result = null;
        Task<AdminDMSEntities> getUsersAsyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new AdminDMSEntities());
        await getUsersAsyncTask;
        return result;
    }
```

and this is the change to the controller:

```
public class UsersController : AsyncController
{
    private AdminDMSEntities adminEntities = null;
    //
    // GET: /User/

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (adminEntities == null)
        {
            adminEntities = await AdminDMSEntities.AdminDMSEntitiesAsync();
        }
        return View(adminEntities.UserList);
    }
}
```

The result is that adminEntities are containing an instance of the class, but there are no users in the list (there should be 11).

EDIT2: Since i was told that creating new task is not the right thing to do, I went with the first suggested approach removin AdminDMSEntities class from the code. My thanks to Darin for helping me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [`asynchronous controller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The idea is to have your controller derive from the [`AsyncController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) class instead of the `Controller` class. This class provides methods that allow you to perform asynchronous operations.

For example:

```
public class MyController: AsyncController
{
    public void IndexAsync()
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
        var client = new SomeClient();
        client.GetUsersCompleted += (s, e) => 
        {
            UserList = new List<User>();
            AsyncManager.Parameters["users"] = e.Result.Select(
                w => new User(
                    w.Guid, 
                    w.TrusteeType, 
                    w.Username, 
                    w.Email, 
                    w.LastLogin, 
                    w.PasswordChanged, 
                    w.IsUsingTempPassword
                )
            )
            .ToList();
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();            
        };
        client.GetUsersAsync();
    }

    public ActionResult IndexCompleted(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {
        return View(users);
    }
}
```

and if you are using .NET 4.5 you could even take advantage of the new `async` keyword simplifying the asynchronous code even further. This is possible if you refactor your data access layer to the new pattern (i.e. return Tasks):

```
public class MyController: AsyncController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var client = new SomeClient();
        var users = await client.GetUsersAsync().Select(
            w => new User(
                w.Guid, 
                w.TrusteeType, 
                w.Username, 
                w.Email, 
                w.LastLogin, 
                w.PasswordChanged, 
                w.IsUsingTempPassword
            )
        )
        .ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
}
```

Comment: It look like what I need, but I cant get it running. My GetUsersAsync method comes from automatically generated Service reference, it is returning "void", so I used the code from constructor in my original post and I have to create task using `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => client.GetUsersAsync());` Unofrtunately null is still being passed to the view.

Comment: You should not create a new Task. You should use directly the autogenerated client instance in the controller action. And subscribe to the `GetUsersCompleted` event as shown in my answer.

Comment: I deleted previous comment, I just found the definition of autogenerated method. I will try your approach and then get back to you

Comment: I went through the definition and my autogenerated method returns only "void". So I tried what I posted as "EDIT" in my original post. However it would be much better to have async method returning user array or user list, then I could go for your suggestion utilizing async method. I will try the first solution now

Comment: First solution works properly. But I liked async-await solution much more, I need to figure out how to change the methods for service to try it out.